# Tabbed ViewPager pre-honeycomb

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I've been trying to setup a ViewPager with tabs in the ActionBar, but I also wanted to support older API levels (pre-ActionBar levels).

Since nearly everything that I'm trying to do in order to setup the tabbed ViewPager requires API level 11 and I can only seem to get the support libraries to go so far, I'm unsure as to what I should do.

I know I could use a TabWidget with a HorizontalScrollView to get the job done, however I don't think it will be efficient enough, nor provide the same user experience/usability/interaction, right?

or

Should I use the [Sherlock Action Bar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

Sherlock Action Bar is recommended for using ActionBar in API < 4.0 not only for ViewPager movements it provides navigation like "Up" button and actionItems behaviour also if you need to in future migrate the app to support apis >= 4.0 the changes are very very little.

Comment: How would you access navigation like "Up"? Is it for transitioning between activities?